# DES decryption issue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, encryption, des

I am using DES decryption with ECB mode. I am using the following code for decryption :

```
NSString *token = @"kRAz86UoZd5tFKf0xv8TKg==";
NSString *key = @"meristem";

const void *vplainText;
size_t plainTextBufferSize;

NSData *EncryptData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:token options:0];
plainTextBufferSize = [EncryptData length];
vplainText = [EncryptData bytes];

//plainTextBufferSize = [token length];
//vplainText = (const void *) [token UTF8String];

CCCryptorStatus ccStatus;
uint8_t *bufferPtr = NULL;
size_t bufferPtrSize = 0;
size_t movedBytes;

bufferPtrSize = (plainTextBufferSize + kCCBlockSize3DES) & ~(kCCBlockSize3DES - 1);
bufferPtr = malloc( bufferPtrSize * sizeof(uint8_t));
memset((void *)bufferPtr, 0x0, bufferPtrSize);

NSString *initVec = @"init Vec";
const void *vkey = (const void *) [key UTF8String];
const void *vinitVec;
vinitVec = (const void *) [initVec UTF8String];

ccStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt,
                   kCCAlgorithmDES,
                   kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode,
                   vkey, //"123456789012345678901234", //key
                   kCCKeySizeDES,
                   NULL,// vinitVec, //"init Vec", //iv,
                   vplainText, //"Your Name", //plainText,
                   plainTextBufferSize,
                   (void *)bufferPtr,
                   bufferPtrSize,
                   &movedBytes);

NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)bufferPtr length:(NSUInteger)movedBytes];
NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"dis is data %@",decodedString);
```

Here, you can see that my encrypted string is **kRAz86UoZd5tFKf0xv8TKg==** and its result is **vishal thakur**. But by using the above code for decryption, I am getting only **vishal t**. I cant understand why am not getting the full string. Please can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Try more bigger buffer for result.

Comment: @Cy-4AH Can u please tell me how can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited:**
I think it has something to do with `plainTextBufferSize`, and this cause the problem as you call it in your `CCCrypt` function.

Try changing its value before `CCCrypt` function.

Comment: no luck! :( but I soved out the problem by changing this line plainTextBufferSize = [EncryptData length]; into plainTextBufferSize = [EncryptData length]+1; And thanks a lot!!

Comment: You're welcome. (I didn't see that line of the code! `plainTextBufferSize = [EncryptData length];` :D) I knew the problem was with `plainTextBufferSize`, but as I didn't notice that line, my first answer was totally wrong, as any value you assign to `plainTextBufferSize` would be replaced with `[EncryptData length]`. I edited my answer to be no longer misleading.

Comment: and as a suggestion: answer your own question and accept the answer for others who may have this problem. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I have solved my issue by replacing this line

```
plainTextBufferSize = [EncryptData length];
```

into

```
plainTextBufferSize = [EncryptData length]+1;
```